# Access object properties React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, object

I have a response from the server that looks like this

```
[  
   {  
      "metric":{  
         "id":"b66178b8-dc18-11e8-9f8b-f2801f1b9fd1",
         "name":"Detector de fum bucatarie",
         "metricValueType":"DOUBLE",
         "metricType":"DEVICE_VALUE",
         "groupUUID":null,
         "projectUUID":null,
         "companyUUID":"ccab28ed-3dcf-411f-8748-ec7740ae559c",
         "unit":null,
         "formula":null
      },
      "data":{  
         "1550150771819":"10.310835857351371"
      }
   }
]
```

Data property contains a hashMap with Timestamp and a Value. 
When I try to get any value I recive this error:

`myErrorTypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'metricValues.metric.id')`

How can I access a property ? I tried both methods :

`metricValues.metric.id`

and

`metricValues["metric"]["id"]`

How can I get the hashMap values?
I already tried this :

```
const timestamp = Object.keys(metricValues.data)[0];
const values = Object.values(metricValues.data)[0];
```

Comment: The data structure in your snippet is an array with an object in it. You can write `metricValues[0].metric.id` to get the `id` of that only object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is an array of objects. So even though your data has only one object, still it is an array of objects. 
your object is at index 0 of the array.
You can access the metric Id as follows,

metricValues[0].metric.id

Answer (score 0):

Try This (put that `[0]`)

```
metricValues[0].metric.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response from the server is an array. And the metric object is in the first element of that array.

To access the id inside the metric object you need to pass the index at which that object is present in the array which is 0 here.

That's why use :

```
metricValues[0].metric.id
```